# What is new in Entity Framework 6.1.2?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I noticed that EF 6.1.2 was released last week on NuGet, but I'm having trouble finding any release notes of what was updated.  The CodePlex site only has notes up to 6.1.1.  Where can I find this information or is it simply not available yet?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Version 6.1.2 fixes several bugs. Read this [Blogpost of the EF team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/12/22/ef6-1-2-rtm-available.aspx) on the ADO.Net blog:

> **What’s in EF6.1.2?**
>
> EF6.1.2 is mostly about bug fixes, you [can see a list of the fixes
>   included in EF6.1.2 on our CodePlex site](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced?keyword=&status=Closed&type=All&priority=All&release=EF%206.1.2&assignedTo=All&component=All&sortField=AssignedTo&sortDirection=Ascending&page=0&reasonClosed=Fixed).

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like the downvote brigade is running in full force, but this was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: yeah, this downvoting is annoying. Subscribe to the RSS feed of the ADO.net blog and you'll get notified about new versions and tips about EF.